# All CSS assets are loaded after each refresh page in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with load applications assets. I use [twitter-bootstrap-rails gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails). It genetate a css file, and i see loading after every refresh page.
I see its in console:

```
Started GET "/assets/plans.self-d7fb8f00efb616455393cb653247ba61a0d1b0c34e60903d02b3d1756e1dd654.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-27 19:59:20 +0300
```

plans - is my model.
Assets for all models will load if i open one of applications page. I dont use css class from many assets, and want load only some of assets.
How i can doing this?

Comment: Do you have a `require_tree .` directive near the top of your application.css?

Comment: How do your `stylesheet_link_tag` declarations look like? How does your application.css look like?

Comment: there may be some way to load stylesheets on demand. But, it's more efficient to load all stylesheets compiled in one file, only once. That's what rails do in production environnement. In you re actual environement: development (i guess), all assets are loaded separatly, for ease of use and debug.

Comment: Yes, i have  *= require_tree and require_self in application.css